# minimizar notepad.exe programa externo

Tags: c#

Gostaria de  ter um Button ao clicar nele no meu form o notepad.exe minimizar para barra do windows.como que eu faço esse código não tenho minima ideia ?

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

   System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   string windir = null;
   prc.StartInfo.FileName = windir + @"filename";
   prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
   prc.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método [`Process.GetProcessesByName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8) para obter um array dos processos ativos no sistema que compartilham um mesmo nome de processo.
Use a função [`ShowWindow()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN) da API do windows com os parâmetros [`Process.MainWindowHandle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netframework-4.8) que informa o handler da janela principal do processo e `SW_MINIMIZE` que informa `ShowWindow()` de que a janela deve ser minimizada.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            foreach (var item in localByName)
            {
                ShowWindow(item.MainWindowHandle, SW_MINIMIZE);
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado, Augusto Vasques